# How do I do striped textarea? (CSS)

Tags: html, css, sass, styles

How do I do striped textarea? I didn't get the look in design.

Screenshot:[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please share your attempts

Comment: a repeating-linear-gradient maybe?

Comment: Or a background SVG (background-size depending on line height), but I'd play first with gradients _for fun_ :p

Answer (score 1):

there is CSS function for that.

```
    repeating-linear-gradient()
```

It is a linear-gradient() function that repeats itselt and gives a **stripes** effect.

Check out the doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient).

Comment: How do I use a dashed line?

Comment: If you are talking about a dashed border, this CSS property and value will do the work.

Comment: border-style: dotted